# Are these equally fast? (Map and List)

Tags: c++, list, vector

Which one is faster? Fragment A or Fragment B? Or would they be more or less the same?

I know they are impractical programs; this is only for learning purposes.

```
list<string> A(1000);
//assign random string values to each entry in A (code not shown). 
//At least one of the strings is "test"
list<string>::iterator it;

//BEGINNING OF FRAGMENT A:
for(it=A.begin(); it!=A.end(); it++){
    if((*it)=="test"){
        cout << "found";
        break;
    }
}
//END OF FRAGMENT A
```

.

```
map<string,bool> B(1000);
//assign random string values to each entry in B (code not shown). 
//At least one of the strings is "test".
//B[any string]=1 (code not shown)
//
//BEGINNING OF FRAGMENT B:
if(B["test"]) cout << "found";
////END OF FRAGMENT B
```

Comment: Why don't you simply test it? Write a small program and stop the execution-time (on linux you can use `time`). [This blog](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/) might give you a good start on benchmarking.

Comment: Should the time to fill the data structures be included in the overall timing? Is this part of a school assignment?

Comment: @outis I've never taken a programming or Compsci class

Comment: @Björn Pollex I know I could do that, but I also wanted an explanation.

Comment: @alberteinstein: Then do the benchmarking and post the results as part of your question. Then you can ask *Why is X faster than Y?* which is a way better question.

Comment: The right question to ask would be for the difference between `std::find(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), val)` and `mymap.find(val)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First* of all you should profile.

*Second;* 
they're not equal as `B["test"]` will insert an element if it isnt in the container.
`if(B.count("test") != 0)` is the correct way to do it.

*Third;* B is faster, and will gain the larger the container is as it will perform a binary search in a sorted container; *O(log(N))* instead of *O(N)*.

*Forth;* std::hash_set or hash_map is probably what youre looking for as it is even more fast then std::map

Comment: +1 for pointing out the different semantics. For the complexity, see my comment on @Anders' answer.

Answer (score 1):

B is by far faster. In A you have to traverse the entire list which is an `O(n)` operation.

Maps are usually implemented as trees, giving `O(log(n))` time.

Comment: Note that just because the map has better asymptotic complexity, it does not mean that it is always faster. It is probably the case here, there are scenarios (e.g. when working with small sets of integers) when the vector can be the faster one.

Answer (score 1):

map is faster to find by key information.

Answer (score 1):

Searching through a linked `list` has linear complexity, O(n), whereas searching through a `map` will have logarithmic complexity, O(log n).

Alternatively, you could use the [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) type.

Comment: The even better alternative would be a `unordered_set` (either from Boost, TR1 or C++11), since nothing in the question suggests that ordering is required.

Comment: Thank you, I think set or unordered set may be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

List search has a worst case complexity of O(n) where as map would do it in O(log n).
so map is faster when it comes to lookup.